# Uniqueness of global Python objects void in sub-interpreters?

Tags: mod-wsgi, uwsgi, python

I have a question about inner-workings of Python sub-interpreter initialization (from Python/C API) and Python `id()` function. More precisely, about handling of global module objects in a WSGI Python containers (like uWSGI used with nginx and mod_wsgi on Apache).

The following code works as expected (isolated) in both of the mentioned environments, but I can not explain to my self **why the `id()` function always returns the same value** per variable, regardless of the process/sub-interpreter in which it is executed.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os, sys

def log(*msg):
    print(">>>", *msg, file=sys.stderr)

class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def __str__(self):
        return self.x
    def set(self, x):
        self.x = x

a = A("one")
log("class instantiated.")

def application(environ, start_response):

    output = "pid = %d\n" % os.getpid()
    output += "id(A) = %d\n" % id(A)
    output += "id(a) = %d\n" % id(a)
    output += "str(a) = %s\n\n" % a

    a.set("two")

    status = "200 OK"
    response_headers = [
        ('Content-type', 'text/plain'), ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))
    ]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

I have tested this code in uWSGI with one master process and 2 workers; and in mod_wsgi using a deamon mode with two processes and one thread per process. The typical output is:

> pid = 15278
>   id(A) = 139748093678128
>   id(a) = 139748093962360
>   str(a) = one

on first load, then:

> pid = 15282
>   id(A) = 139748093678128
>   id(a) = 139748093962360
>   str(a) = one

on second, and then

> pid = 15278  | pid = 15282
>   id(A) = 139748093678128
>   id(a) = 139748093962360
>   str(a) = two

on every other. As you can see, `id()` (memory location) of both the class and the class instance remains the same in **both** processes (first/second load above), while at the same time class instances live in a separate context (otherwise the second request would show "two" instead of "one")!

I suspect the answer might be hinted by Python docs:

> **`id(object)`**:
>
> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer (or long integer) which 
>   is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. Two
>   objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same `id()` value.

But if that indeed is the reason, I'm troubled by the next statement that claims the `id()` value is object's address!

While I appreciate the fact this could very well be just a Python/C API "clever" feature that solves (or rather *fixes*) a [problem of caching object references (pointers) in 3rd party extension modules](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Multiple_Python_Sub_Interpreters), I still find this behavior to be inconsistent with... well, common sense. Could someone please explain this?

I've also noticed mod_wsgi imports the module in each process (i.e. **twice**), while uWSGI is importing the module only **once** for both processes. Since the uWSGI master process does the importing, I suppose it seeds the children with copies of that context. Both workers work independently afterwards (deep copy?), while at the same time using the same object addresses, seemingly. (Also, a worker gets reinitialized to the original context upon reload.)

I apologize for such a long post, but I wanted to give enough details.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking; I'd give a more concise answer if the question was more specific.

First, the id of an object is, in fact--at least in CPython--its address in memory.  That's perfectly normal: two objects in the same process at the same time can't share an address, and an object's address never changes in CPython, so the address works neatly as an  id.  I don't know how this violates common sense.

Next, note that a backend process may be spawned in two very distinct ways:

- A generic WSGI backend handler will fork processes, and then each of the processes will start a backend.  This is simple and language-agnostic, but wastes a lot of memory and wastes time loading the backend code repeatedly.
- A more advanced backend will load the Python code once, and then fork copies of the server after it's loaded.  This causes the code to be loaded only once, which is much faster and reduces memory waste significantly.  This is how production-quality WSGI servers work.

However, the end result in both of these cases is identical: separate, forked processes.

So, why are you ending up with the same IDs?  That depends on which of the above methods is in use.

- With a generic WSGI handler, it's happening simply because each process is doing essentially the same thing.  So long as processes are doing the same thing, they'll tend to end up with the same IDs; at some point they'll diverge and this will no longer happen.
- With a pre-loading backend, it's happening because this initial code happens only once, before the server forks, so it's guaranteed to have the same ID.

However, *either way*, once the fork happens they're separate objects, in separate contexts.  There's no significance to objects in separate processes having the same ID.

Comment: My primary question was about `id()` returning same values in different processes. That implied the code in two python sub-interpreters occupied the same memory space.. **But** I was forgetting about a little thing called **virtual memory address**! Of course the data is mapped to different physical address. D'oh! Thanks!

Comment: Note that with pre-loading, a lot of data actually will use the same physical memory--copy-on-write (COW) memory blocks.

Comment: I hate to disagree, however, when you say a generic WSGI handler will have the same ids without forking, I believe that to be false.

Answer (score 2):

This is simple to explain by way of a demonstration. You see, when uwsgi creates a new process, it forks the interpreter. Now, forks have interesting memory properties:

```
import os, time

if os.fork() == 0:
    print "child first " + str(hex(id(os)))
    time.sleep(2)
    os.attr = 'test'
    print "child second " + str(hex(id(os)))
else:
    time.sleep(1)
    print "parent first " + str(hex(id(os)))
    time.sleep(2)
    print "parent second " + str(hex(id(os)))
    print os.attr
```

Output:

```
child first 0xb782414cL
parent first 0xb782414cL
child second 0xb782414cL
parent second 0xb782414cL
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    print os.attr
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'attr'
```

Although the objects seem to reside at the same memory addr, they are different objects, but this is not python, but the os.

edit: I suspect the reason that mod_wsgi imports twice is that it creates further processes via calling python rather than forking. uwsgi's approach is better because it can use less memory. fork's page sharing is COW (copy on write).

Comment: Yeah, I forgot `id()` returns virtual address not physical.. Of course.. Thanks!

Comment: It's an easy mistake to make, no problem.

Comment: ..it happens when you keep banging your head on a single question, instead of taking a break and a fresh look. :)

Comment: uWSGI and mod_wsgi both do fork (no exec or separate invocation), there shouldn't be a difference. Am suspicious about the accuracy of the statement that uWSGI only loads it once.

Comment: ah, in that case I guess it depends on when the fork happens, ie whether the fork is before the import or not.

Comment: Loading the application before the fork has a lot of danger because it is possible that it will allocate resources in a way that will cause problems if then used from multiple process after a fork. When doing this one generally needs the ability to have a hook where the application can do special fixup tasks after the fork to deal with such issues, or as point to defer resource allocations/setup to. I know of no such facility in uWSGI and have never seen any document guiding web applications on what they need to do. Having import/fork as a default behavior would thus be dangerous.

Comment: @graham I can not _guarantee_ uWSGI is loading module only once, but it sure seems like it looking at the error log file. The `class instantiated.` string from the script above appears **only once**. After initializing sockets and hooks, uWSGI imports the Python module, locates `application` callable, and only than spawns master process and two worker processes.

Comment: @stevie If that is the case then am a bit surprised. You just can't know what an application is going to do if preloaded and initialised prior to the fork. For many applications it may indeed work, but for others it may just cause problems. I would have gone with default behaviour of lazy import after fork and only allow preloading before fork as an option where people do it knowing the possible consequences. Worth also pointing out that copy on write with Python not that effective because of reference counts on objects. That is, stuff isn't really ever read only, even for code.

Comment: @dan, WSGI is an interface specification, not an implementation so your comment doesn't really make much sense. You would need to clarify what implementation of a WSGI hosting mechanism you are talking about. Am not sure how you see threads even coming into this anyway.

Comment: @graham, cow will work find for python, if a reference count changes, the page the reference count is on will be copied. You are of course right, WSGI is a specification. What I meant was, creating a new thread after import time will have some of the same problems as forking after import time.

Comment: @graham, could you point me to some reference on how is initialization (with a preloaded python code) of a newly created sub-interpreted generally done? I understand this will be done automatically by the OS if you actually fork the master process. But how is it done when you want several Python sub-interpreters inside a single process/thread?

Comment: @dan, yes I know that COW works. What I am saying is that reference counting causes one of the main reasons for using it to be defeated quite easily. That is people rely on COW to allow memory to be shared between processes and keep resident memory footprint down, but in Python, use an object and even executing code will in most cases causes the copy to be created, so memory benefits evaporate. Thus only saving on cost of loading application multiple times.

Comment: @dan with respect to using threads rather than fork after import, it isn't quite the same. How you deal with synchronisation across processes is different to what you need to do with threads. Also, although you might be able to make use of a single client database connection within a process from multiple threads with appropriate locking, trying to reuse same client database connection from multiple processes is a potential for disaster. This is why preloading can be dangerous, because if that had side effect of creating a pool of database connections which are then inherited, it may fail.

Comment: @stevie, too hard to explain here and not sure entirely what you are wanting to know. If want to know what mod_wsgi does and discuss it in general, then hop onto the mod_wsgi mailing list.

Comment: @graham, btw kudos for the mod_wsgi. Since I first read about it and tried it about a year ago, I always thought you're doing a wonderful job - not just writing quality code, but also excellent/insightful docs! (which is often ignored/skipped/postponed/delayed/etc in open source)